# How to work around the Swift requirement that switch default statement has to be last (after cases)?

Tags: swift

A typical code that used to work fine in all C variants
but somehow is not supported in Swift:

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
var body: some View
{
    var multiplier: CGFloat
    switch(colorScheme)
    {
    @unknown default:
        assertionFailure()
        fallthrough
    case .light:
        multiplier = 0.3
    case .dark:
        multiplier = 0.1
        fallthrough
    }
```

How would I rewrite this in such a fashion that the Swift compiler wouldn't complain?

As a stop gap measure I did:

```
switch(colorScheme)
{
case .light:
    multiplier = 0.3
case .dark:
    multiplier = 0.1
@unknown default:
    preconditionFailure()
}
```

to satisfy the requirement that `default` comes last but this is
obviously NOT the semantics that I want.

I want the code to bomb in debug builds and fallback onto dark or light case in release cases so that the code works in the field.

I guess there should be a change request in Swift filed to remove this requirement. The workaround is in accepted answer but the code a bit too voluminious compared to the same code in the outgoing [whether it's Objective or not] C.

Comment: I don't think you *should* use a switch for this.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to remove all the snark... it doesn't make for particularly good reading and questions that reflect poor etiquette are more likely to be downvoted and ignored.

For what it's worth, I thought various aspects of Swift were overly restrictive when I first started using the language and I've found over time that the restrictiveness leads to much cleaner code with fewer bugs. It's a beautiful language once you get the hang of it.

Comment: How is @unknown default different from default in C runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because defaults come last, common logic has to come afterwards…

```swift
let multiplier: Double = {
  switch colorScheme {
  case .light:
    break
  case .dark:
    return 0.1
  @unknown default:
    assertionFailure()
  }

  return 0.3
} ()
```

…or be defined early and referred to in later usage.

```swift
let multiplier: Double
let lightMultiplier = 0.3
switch colorScheme {
case .light:
  multiplier = lightMultiplier
case .dark:
  multiplier = 0.1
@unknown default:
  assertionFailure()
  multiplier = lightMultiplier
}
```

Comment: that let on top is the reason this is the accepted answer. Thanks for edufication.

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

```
switch colorScheme {
case .dark:
    multiplier = 0.1
case .light:
    fallthrough
@unknown default:
    assertionFailure("unknown colorScheme \(colorScheme)")
    multiplier = 0.3
}
```

Although I personally think it would be more clear to use:

```
switch colorScheme {
case .dark:
    multiplier = 0.1
case .light:
    multiplier = 0.3
@unknown default:
    assertionFailure("unknown colorScheme \(colorScheme)")
    multiplier = 0.3
}
```

In the second example you don't use a `fallthrough` and thus break any dependency between what the `.light` state does and what the default future unknown `colorScheme` does (even though as of now it uses the same `multiplier` as the light scheme).

In the shop I work at it would be considered "Swiftier" (i.e. more expressive of intent and thus coded in the spirit with which Swift is designed) to write it in this latter fashion.